# Store variable from preg_split, and use it it comination with the word

Tags: php, foreach, preg-split

I am still facing a major problem, which in a previous question was unfortunally not answered. I want to do the following:

I have a custom made cms, where i want to use shortcodes to use plugins. It is working like this:

```
this is a text
[plugin-blog]
this is more text
and some more
[plugin-contact]
```

What it outputs is this:

```
this is a text
include_once('plugins/blog/blog.php'); <- loads specific file for plugin
this is more text
and some more
include_once('plugins/contact/contact.php'); <- loads specific file for plugin
```

This is working fine, but what i want is to have a specific id from the plugin, which i want to call with `[plugin-blog 2]`. I need to store the number of the plugin and use it later inside the php file of the plugin like this `SELECT * FROM 'plugin_db' WHERE 'id' = $value_from_shortcode`

How can I do this? I am totally blank on how to approach this problem. I tried literally everything, but either the loop is not working anymore, of the number is not saved with the comination of the plugin name. I have the following code:

```
$regex = '~\[plugin-([^]]+)]~';
        $content_one = htmlspecialchars_decode($page['content_one']);
        $parts = preg_split($regex, $content_one, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);

        foreach($parts as $k => $v){
            if($k & 1)
                include_once('plugins/'.$v.'/'.$v.'.php');
            else
                echo htmlspecialchars_decode($v);
        }
```

Comment: You're facing the consequences of a very poor design and following anti-patterns, and poor understanding of how php really works. This is actually not at any rate problem with preg_split, but probably with you using binary operator in place of boolean for some reason? What did you expect from `$k & 1`? Compare it to 1? In php you do `1 == $k` instead.

Comment: Or that is odd number check? As each odd number has last 1 in it's binary representation?

Comment: The $k & 1 is the only part I did not wrote myself, but a developer in the team, which made it working. Not sure what is does. My knowledge of php is kinda basic on this matter :( I hope someone can help me.

Comment: edited the &k & 1. I don't understand why he used an & sign there.

Comment: The `$k & 1` is mandatory to treat all plugins.

Comment: I see, my fault :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retrieve the id and the name with:

```
    foreach($parts as $k => $v){
        if($k & 1) {
            $id = preg_replace('/\D+/', '', $v);
            $v = preg_replace('/\d+/', '', $v);
            echo "id = $id\n";
            include ('plugins/'.$v.'/'.$v.'.php');
        } else {
            echo htmlspecialchars_decode($v);
        }
    }
```

**Note:** keep the test `$k & 1` to deal with all plugins.

Comment: Perfect! That's it! I tried a lot with preg_replace, but just did not find a solution. Very many thanks!

Comment: I tried to implement multiple shortcodes now, but that unfortunally does not work. Why can that happen?

Comment: Ah I see now. I of course got an error in my query in the plugin itself, since i use a same query multiple times for different keys. Not an idea on how to approach that, but I guess that can be solved simply. Got any idea what i mean ^^?

Comment: @Saypontigohe: Not sure I well understand but you could call the query inside the loop.

Comment: I am calling the query inside the file, but since a while loop can only be used once, it does not show the same plugin multiple time for different group id's ( `$id` ). I am trying to find a solution, but i think that is just an easy step I haven't seen yet. Your answer has helped me out already!

Comment: It was my fault for using include_once instead of include inside the plugin. You saved my whole week spending solving the problem. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Your variables from parent scope should be available as global variables  in your included file:

Given: below is test.php

```
<?php

$foo = "test";

include('./b.php');
```

And this is b.php:

```
<?php echo $foo;
```

Running `test.php` will output `test`

So in your case `$k` and `$v` will be available in file that you include, so you can do something alike:

```
if (1 == $k) {
    $id = $v;

    include_once('plugins/'.$v.'/'.$v.'.php');
}
```

And please consider learning PHP and best practices.

Comment: I use this already, but my main problem is to have the id seperate from the string (right now, it outputs  include_once('plugins/blog 2/blog 2.php') which of course cannot be found). And even if I seperate the id, it still needs to know it is part of the plugin name. I am busy learning with PHP, but am blank on this spot particular